# WPF MVVM application - ICollectionView/Threading/General Questions

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a few questions regarding to building WPF MVVM applications.

1) I'm using ICollectionView objects for databound controls such as ListView and ComboBox. I found this was the simplest way of gaining access to/tracking the selected item of these controls. What is the best way to replace the contents of ICollectionView? Currently I'm doing it like so:

```
    private ICollectionView _files;

public ICollectionView Files {
    get { return _files; }
}

void _service_GetFilesCompleted(IList<SomeFile> files) {
    this.IsProcessing = false;
    _files = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(files);
    _files.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(FileSelectionChanged);
    OnPropertyChanged("Files");
}
```

I didn't know whether it was necessary to reattach the handler every time I refresh the list of files?

2) Now that I've got my head round it, I am starting to like the MVVM pattern. However, one concept I'm not completely sure about is how to send notifications back down to the view. Currently I am doing this by binding to properties on my ViewModel. For example, in the above code I have an "IsProcessing" property that I use to determine whether to display a ProgressBar. Is this the recommended approach?

3) Following on from 2) - there doesn't seem to be a standard way to handle exceptions in an MVVM application. One thought I had was to have one method on my ViewModel base class that handled exceptions. I could then inject an IMessagingService that was responsible for relaying any error messages. A concrete implementation of this could use MessageBox.

4) I have a few tasks that I want to perform asynchronously. Rather than adding this logic directly in my service I created a decorator service that runs the underlying service methods on a new thread. It exposes a number of events that my ViewModel can then subscribe to. I have listed the code below. I understand that BackgroundWorker is a safer option but did not know whether it was suitable for running multiple asynchronous tasks at once?:

```
    public void BeginGetFiles()
    {
        ThreadStart thread = () => {
            var result = _serviceClient.GetUserFiles(username, password);
            GetFilesCompleted(result.Files);
        };

        new Thread(thread).Start();
    }
```

Finally, I realize that there are a number of MVVM frameworks projects that handle some of these requirements. However, I want to understand how to achieve the above using built-in functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have ListViews and ComboBoxes, you should really be considering an `ObservableCollection<>` to bind to these controls.  Adding and removing items from the collection will automatically notify the control the property has changed.

If you're doing background processing, you can look at the BackgroundWorker or DispatcherTimer to handle updates to the UI.  These both have the capability of acting on the UI thread, and can be thread safe.

Comment: I never need to add/remove individual items from the collection; the collection is always replaced. Also ICollectionView seemed the simplest way to get the current item from a ListView - unless you can suggest an alternative. Yes I am aware of BackgroundWorker - please see my question regarding multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected item from a combo box, expose an INotifyCollectionChanged object such as ObservableCollection and bind it to the itemsource, then create another property for the current item and binding ComboBox.SelectedItem (or ComboBox.SelectedValue if required) to it. You will need to manage the selection when updating the collection.

On the face of it, ICollectionView seems like the obvious choice but the WPF implementation really forces your hand on some threading code that you really shouldn't be troubled with.

I used ICollectionView and CollectionViewSource recently (for filtering) and have become frustrated with how many dispatcher issues have crept in. Today I am probably going to revert to the method i describe above.